# MongoDB Proposal about notablescan option

Tags: mongodb

I'm a heavy mongo user.

I issue this ticket from strong sense of impending crisis and wanted to know how others thinks about this.

This proposal is about the feature of the notablescan option.

This is not for the programers but for the mongo-operators who operates more than hundreds GB of collections regularly.

### WISH

- I want to use notablescan on the production DB.
- I want to apply notablescan to per DB or per COLLECTION.

### REASON

We can kill our mongod easily by sending query with no indexed field to the more than hundreds GB of collection.

To make matters worse, we'll get same results by specifying non-existent field cause by simple typo.

The feature of notablescan option can prevent these catastrophic incidents.

Especially, on the production DB.

### ADDITIONAL

But currently, likely to add this sentence to mongo-docs.

> Don't run production :program:`mongod` instances with
>   :parameter:`notablescan` because preventing table scans can
>   potentially   affect queries in all databases, including
>   administrative queries.

I think, this is the wrong policy to keep our mongo system safety.

On the contrary, I want to come to be that the notablescan option is applicable per DB or per COLLECTION.

Please vote this ticket (around right-top) if you agree with me.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15561

Comment: Hi Hiroaki. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming, but about getting votes for a JIRA ticket. It's nice that you care about improving MongoDB. 
However, StackOverflow (or any other StackExchange site) is not an appropriate place for this kind of content.

Comment: Are you aware of the  [`$maxScan`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxScan/) query option and [`$maxTimeMS`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxTimeMS/) cursor option? Both can be used to mitigate potentially potentially poor performing queries. As noted in the MongoDB documentation, the `notablescan` option is a very coarse filter and in addition to blocking adhoc/typo'd queries it may accidentally interfere with some administrative commands.

Comment: Another obvious administrative approach is to limit direct access to your production databases. If you can't trust your operators you could have them use an administrative UI or perhaps require a global `mongorc.js` that automatically appends a small `$maxScan` limit to all queries by default.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal of what you can do:

In mongodb 2.6.x there is a [$maxTimeMS](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/83621787773/maxtimems-and-query-optimizer-introspection-in) and the [documentation says](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxTimeMS/) that

> The $maxTimeMS operator specifies a cumulative time limit in
>   milliseconds for processing operations on the cursor. MongoDB
>   interrupts the operation at the earliest following interrupt point.

So you can just use this `db.collection.find({...}).maxTimeMS(msTime)` to make sure that you query is not taking too long. And then you can analyse what exactly does not make it in your timelimit and take the actions accordingly.